# Why does iptables NAT work in mininet, but iptables logging does not?

Tags: networking, iptables, mininet

I looked up the *NAT* class in `mininet.nodelib`, it is implemented through *iptables*:

```
self.cmd( 'iptables -I FORWARD',
              '-i', self.localIntf, '-d', self.subnet, '-j DROP' )
self.cmd( 'iptables -A FORWARD',
              '-i', self.localIntf, '-s', self.subnet, '-j ACCEPT' )
self.cmd( 'iptables -A FORWARD',
              '-o', self.localIntf, '-d', self.subnet,'-j ACCEPT' )
self.cmd( 'iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING', 
              '-s', self.subnet, "'!'", '-d', self.subnet, '-j MASQUERADE' )
```

However when I install a logging rule :

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT log: " --log-level 4
```

Not a single /related/ entry appears in the `/var/log/kern.log` file (it works, if I run the same rule with no `mininet`).

Thanks in advance!

## Edit:

To be more precise, here is what I tried to do:

```
mininet>h2 iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT log: " --log-level 3
mininet>h2 iptables -I OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT log: " --log-level 3
mininet>h2 ping h0
.... normal ping output ....
mininet>h2 wget h0
.... index.html being saved on disk ....
mininet>h2 grep "IPT log" /var/log -R
```

As `grep` shows, there is no a single relevant line in the logs, despite multiple ICMP message being sent by ping and TCP communication performed by `wget`.

## Edit2:

Here is my iptables rules, after the experiments (sorry for the text-picture): 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **INPUT** chain will contain only packets whose destination is the local machine, not packets that are being forwarded.

A packet that is being routed (forwarded) by the node (in this case, the machine containing the iptables rules) will pass through the following chains:

> **PREROUTING** -> **FORWARD** -> **POSTROUTING**

If you want to log all the packets that are being forwarded, you need to change the **INPUT** chain with the **FORWARD** chain in your log rule.

If you want to log only packets that that are being **NAT**d, you need to use the **POSTROUTING** chain and the **nat** table in your log rule.

**EDIT**

Since the iptables rules (in the OUTPUT chain from your experiment) targeting LOG are being triggered (based on your screenshot), we can rule out any `iptables` [log rules] problem.

The issue must be somewhere else, such as the logging facility service (eg, `syslog`).

Comment: If I install the same rule on PREROUTING of the NAT-box, or on the OUTPUT chain of the "packet-source" machine, it still has no effect:
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT log: " --log-level 4`

Comment: Can you try to use -I instead of -A ? (This will insert the log rule at the head of the table, instead of appending it to the tail, ruling out the possibility of any previous rules being preventing the log rule to be reached).

Comment: Just did, no effect. I'll expand the question to account for these experiments.

Comment: Is your syslog configuration triggering [as in, writing to any log file] any messages with log level 3 ?

Comment: I do not know the triggering level. I just installed the rule for all the levels `--log-level 1`, 2, 3, 4. Also outside mininet `--log-level 4` worked

Comment: The experiments in your new edit should trigger the `iptables` log rule. Can you please update your question with the output of `iptables -L -v | grep 'IPT log'` right after a new `ping` and `wget` experiment with the OUTPUT chain log rule?

Comment: I posted the output to the question

Comment: From your output, the logging rules are being triggered (the first field is the number of packets that triggered that rule). So the problem must be elsewhere (probably in the logging facility service, such as syslog), not in the `iptables` rules itself.

Comment: It may because of the network namespace does not do iptables logging . See http://serverfault.com/questions/691730/iptables-log-rule-inside-a-network-namespace